# JMeter preprocessor did not support JS

Tags: jmeter

I am going to do some test research about APIs, and I choose JMeter as the tool. But I cant use JavaScript in JSR223 PreProcessor. I even dont have the options of JS at the ScriptLanguage drop-down menu. Please help me.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: what java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn engine which was providing JavaScript support has been [removed recently](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372), if you **really** need to use JavaScript in your JSR223 Test Elements you will either have to downgrade you Java to the version where Nashorn is still there (the lowest version JMeter can run on is [OpenJDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

Alternatively you can use [GraalVM](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3291322/oracle-switch-now-from-nashorn-javascript-engine-to-graalvm.html) which brings JavaScript support into the latest JDK versions

And last but not the least, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy as the scripting language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so it might be a good opportunity to consider migration to Groovy as it has much better performance comparing to JavaScript and other scripting options. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)